# ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined] when adding HTML output

Tags: node.js, tdd, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using karma and jasmine for some unit testing.  I'd like an html output instead of checking the console / terminal and found this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-htmlfile-reporter which is perfect for my requirements.

When I run it I get an error :

```
    `ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined]
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
    at onBrowserStart (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/reporters/base.js:14:20)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:15:22)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at onStart (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/browser.js:128:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:15:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:117:20)
    at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
    at Manager.onClientMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:488:38)
    at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:39:10)
```

I've hunted on google for an answer but yet to find one, if I remove the 'html' from the reports in the config it works fine.  I've not used jasmine / karma before so unsure where to look for help.

The part of the config related to reports:     `

```
   reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

  htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'tests/units.html'
  },``
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: did you find a solution? having the same issue here

Comment: @marcellscarlett - no, i just settled with the console output instead.  I read there ware some issues with the versions and so on but the versions I ave should work together and apparently the bug was fixed but meh

Comment: Had this happen to me just now - with console output - it went away by itself. I'm working with a remote dev server, files mounted on NFS - I'm assuming there was a hiccup with saving a file and Karma watching the files

Answer (score 0):

I switched to karma 0.10 and everything works.

```
$ npm uninstall karma
```

and run following in project root:

```
$ npm install karma@0.10
```

Good luck